# Fatal Error Audio equalization simulation LTSpice

Tags: audio, simulation, ltspice, error-amplifier

I'm doing a 3s audio.wav simulation on LTSpice with the following circuit (3 band pass filters and amplifiers):
[image]

In this example it's boosting the bass and attenuating the highs.

It loads the first second really fast and then it start to take a longer time:
[image]

When done amplifying the highs it gets stuck in 2s of the simulation.

The error I get is Fatal Error: Analysis: Time step too small; time = xxxxx,timestep=1.25e-15: trouble with u3:qx-instance q:u3:1.
Or sometimes it's U6 that fails.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it just me or is the input signal trace not actually connected to R3?

Comment: @TylerStone It is connected, I corrected that on the schematics and it's exactly working like before.

Comment: Falstad can do this in real-time with no wait time and only takes as long to draw the schematic with slider POTs et al. it’s worth learning how.  Spice is so slow unless you reduce  sample quantum time to 100x your maximum frequency.

Comment: Try adding `Rser=0.1 Cpar=1m` to the supplies (builtin parasitics). Maybe also `Rser=1` to the signal source, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had some issues like yours I just put this directives:

```
.options gmin=1e-10 abstol=1e-10 method=gear
```

It will change the toleration standards for your simulation, but not so much that will affect your result.

Comment: Thanks. It did help, but it still cant finish the job.

Comment: Continue to adjust error limits. It will not affect the displayed results which are low resolution not 200dB range

Comment: Could post your .tran directive? I see that  Sunnyskyguy EE75 talked about your sampling time. If your sampling is too high on your .tran you can try changing it to something like 1/1000 to start and adjust accordingly you see fit